# Postgres. INSERT INTO table in stored procedure with array of composite type objects as procedure arguments

Tags: postgresql, insert, composite-types

I have two composite types:

```
CREATE TYPE truck.truck_event_type AS
(
    event_global_key       VARCHAR(100),
    event_type             VARCHAR(50),
    datetime_utc           TIMESTAMP(4),
    file_keys              VARCHAR(200)[],
    status                 VARCHAR(50),
    address                VARCHAR(500),
    client_event_id        VARCHAR(100),
    geo_coordinate         truck.truck_locations_geocoordinate
);
```

And

```
CREATE TYPE truck.truck_locations_geocoordinate AS
(
    latitude         REAL,
    longitude        REAL,
    speed            REAL,
    direction        VARCHAR(2),
    datetime_utc     TIMESTAMP(4)
);
```

As you can see, type `truck.truck_event_type` has an ATTRIBUTE with another composite type. I want to create a procedure that takes an array of `truck.truck_event_type` and `truck global key` and insert them into table.

That's what I've tried to do. The procedure declaration:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE truck.create_event_collection
(
    _truck_global_key      VARCHAR(100),
    _events                truck.truck_event_type[]
)
AS
$$
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO truck.truck_events
    (
        truck_id,
        client_event_id,
        event_global_key,
        event_type,
        datetime_utc,
        file_keys,
        status,
        address,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        speed,
        direction
    )
    SELECT
        t.id,
        e.client_event_id,
        e.event_global_key,
        e.event_type,
        e.datetime_utc,
        e.file_keys,
        e.status,
        e.address,
        e.geo_coordinate.latitude,
        e.geo_coordinate.longitude,
        e.geo_coordinate.speed,
        e.geo_coordinate.direction
    FROM truck.trucks as t
    JOIN unnest(_events) AS e ON TRUE
    WHERE t.truck_global_key = _truck_global_key
    ON CONFLICT (client_event_id) DO NOTHING;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

And I've tried to call it from Postgres directly:

```
CALL truck.create_event_collection
(
    '0be11cd6-eead-47ad-af64-83d714f22ee2',
    ARRAY[
        ('egk_1', 'emergencyphoto', '2020-01-09 15:00:00', ARRAY['1', '2'], 'emergency', 'adr1', 'cid_1', (1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 's', '2020-01-09 15:00:00')::truck.truck_locations_geocoordinate)::truck.truck_event_type,
        ('egk_2', 'statuschanged',  '2020-01-09 16:00:00', ARRAY['3', '4'], 'moving',    'adr2', 'cid_2', (2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 'w', '2020-01-09 16:00:00')::truck.truck_locations_geocoordinate)::truck.truck_event_type
    ]
)
```

Then I got this error:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "geo_coordinate"
LINE 25:         e.geo_coordinate.latitude,
                 ^
QUERY:  INSERT INTO truck.truck_events
    (
        truck_id,
        client_event_id,
        event_global_key,
        event_type,
        datetime_utc,
        file_keys,
        status,
        address,
        latitude,
        longitude,
        speed,
        direction
    )
    SELECT
        t.id,
        e.client_event_id,
        e.event_global_key,
        e.event_type,
        e.datetime_utc,
        e.file_keys,
        e.status,
        e.address,
        e.geo_coordinate.latitude,
        e.geo_coordinate.longitude,
        e.geo_coordinate.speed,
        e.geo_coordinate.direction
    FROM truck.trucks as t
    JOIN unnest(_events) AS e ON TRUE
    WHERE t.truck_global_key = _truck_global_key
    ON CONFLICT (client_event_id) DO NOTHING
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function truck.create_event_collection(character varying,truck.truck_event_type[]) line 4 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42P01
```

What am I doing wrong? My procedure has worked correctly before, when `latitude`, `longitude`, `speed` and `direction` fields were separate fields in `truck.truck_event_type`. How to insert objects which are of composite type of composite type (nested composite type)?

Comment: Found some [information about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41799522/6468198). Seems like it's pg limitation to use `e.geo_coordinate.latitude`.

Comment: drop the e it should work,  the join condition ON TRUE,  when is it false ?.  I'm wondering why use composite types then nest those types.  the Above code is the reason i avoid doing this as one has to reverse the nesting, then break the data apart so it fits neatly in a table.   In the future note the Postgresql Version being used

Comment: Try `(e.geo_coordinate).latitude` - But wouldn't it be a lot easier to simply pass an array of `truck.truck_events` to the function? I don't see the advantage of obfuscating the real table structure with two nested types

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, it works! What about nested types, some weeks ago the type `truck_locations_geocoordinate` was added to db schema.  And it defines a generic structure that is used to load/save coordinates in other tables. Before that my type `event_type` does not contains `geo_coordinate attribute`, there were fields `latitude`, `longitude`, etc. So now I have to change my stored procedure and the way to save it. It is very convenient for server app side to fill data model like that. Maybe I will change my mind if the performance of saving is poor.